# Virtualbox 4.3.26 dkms will not install properly on Linux kernel 4.1

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 15.04

Hello I have a Toshiba Portege r930 with 8 GB of RAM, 320 GB HDD, and core i3 processor running Ubuntu 15.04. On kernel 4.0.5 my Virtualbox dkms works fine and the virtul machines start up correctly however in kernel 4.1 I get the following:
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

`/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first. This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

and:

```
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Machine
Interface: 
IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
```

Also the dkms under kernel 4.1 will not install correctly and  I get the following error message:

```
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.1.0-040100-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.1.0-040100-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.26/build/make.log for more information.
```

Now my question: Is this a virtualbox error a kernel one? Also is there any way for me to fix this or do I have to wait for the programmers of the offending program/kernel to fix this?

Comment: Why do you use an unsupported kernel? Many other modules may not build as well. There must be a good reason to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Version 4.3.28](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) should work just fine with Linux 4.1.